# Kommas, Semikola und Konjunktionen bei kolumnenartigen Aufzählungen

Tags: conjunction, punctuation, list

Betrachten wir folgende zwei Beispiele:

> Eine Küche erhalten Sie bei uns in folgenden Schritten:
>
> - ein Beratungstermin, am besten telefonisch vereinbart
> - mehrere Entwürfe bei/nach dem Termin
> - Küchenmontage, inkl. Anschluss von Wasser- und Abwasserleitungen und Test von Elektrogeräten
> - Entsorgung der alten Küchenmöbel, und zwar am selben Tag
>
> Wenn Sie sich eine neue Küche wünschen,
>
> - vereinbaren Sie, am besten telefonisch, einen Beratungstermin
> - legen wir Ihnen mehrere Entwürfe vor
> - montieren wir die neue Küche, schließen die Wasser- und Abwasserleitungen an und testen die Elektrogeräte
> - entsorgen wir Ihre alten Küchenmöbel, und zwar am selben Tag

Die zweite Aufzählung ist in den Satz integriert, die erste nicht. Kein Stichpunkt ist ein vollständiger Satz. Ferner haben einige Stichpunkte Kommas und teilweise Unter-Aufzählungen innerndrin. Der Inhalt ist weitestgehend irrelevant, er dient lediglich der Dartstellung des syntaktischen Aufbaus.

Wie haben die Stichpunkte zu enden? Zur Wahl stehen das Komma **,**, das Semikolon **;**, der Punkt **.** und die Konjunktion **und**, auch gemischt.

Begründungen sind extremst willkommen.

Duden und Rechtschreibrat verwenden in ihren Texten zwar eigene Stile in dieser Frage, geben nach meinem besten Wissen keine *genaue* Regel für diesen Fall an – oder es ist zumindest verflixt schwierig, eine solche Regel zu extrahieren. Der Leser wird meines Erachtens im Dunkeln gelassen.

Answer (score 5):

Der Rechtschreibrat gibt sehr wohl [Empfehlungen](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf) ab (§71, E2)

> [Gleichrangige Wortgruppen, Teilsätze und Wörter in Aufzählungen werden durch Komma voneinander getrennt] ... E2:  Das Komma (und gegebenenfalls der  Schlusspunkt) kann in kolumnenartigen Aufzählungen fehlen, ...

Ein Strichpunkt oder ein Punkt wären hier vollkommen unangebracht, da es sich nicht um vollständige Sätze handelt (hier bin ich also nicht ganz mit dem Duden - s.u. - einig).

Im Prinzip ist die Entscheidung also mehr eine Frage des typografischen Stils als der Grammatik, die einem die Entscheidung, ob man Satzzeichen verwenden möchte, hier überlässt. Es gibt Empfehlungen, die

- Jedes neue Item ("Bulletpoint") groß beginnen lassen
- Items mit Satzzeichen (Kommas) voneinander trennen

Oder genau das Gegenteil tun.

Der Duden schrieb in einem seiner Newsletter 2005 (nur noch im Internet-Archiv auffindbar)

> Zeichensetzung bei Aufzählungen
>
> Grundsätzlich gibt es bei Aufzählungen, die aus untereinander angeordneten frei stehenden Zeilen bestehen, die Möglichkeit, mit oder ohne Interpunktion am Zeilenende zu schreiben. Handelt es sich um kurze Aufzählungsglieder, die keine Verbindung zum Einleitungssatz haben, empfiehlt es sich im Allgemeinen, keine Satzzeichen zu setzen, ein Doppelpunkt hinter dem Einleitungssatz ist allerdings immer möglich.
>
> Im Augenblick im Angebot[:]
>
> - Frische (oder: frische) Schneckennudeln
> - Knusprige (oder: knusprige) Brezeln
> - Leckere (oder: leckere) Dampfnudeln
>
> Besteht eine Aufzählung aus umfangreicheren Gliedern, kann man neben der interpunktionslosen Variante jedoch auch eine Form mit Satzzeichen am Zeilenende wählen.
>
> Unsere Schüler werden gebeten[:]
>
> - auf den Fluren nicht zu rauchen,
> - keine Essensreste unter den Bänken liegen zu lassen,
> - Müll in die dafür vorgesehenen Behälter zu werfen,
> - leere Flaschen wieder in die Milchbar zu bringen.
>
> Auch ein Semikolon ist in diesem Aufzählungstyp möglich.
>
> Ein Zuschuss zu den Fahrtkosten kann gewährt werden[:]
>
> - wenn keine öffentlichen Verkehrsmittel zu Verfügung stehen;
> - wenn eine Fahrgemeinschaft nicht gegründet werden kann;
> - bei körperbehinderten Mitarbeitern.
>
> Entscheidet man sich für eine Interpunktionsvariante, ist zu beachten, dass das letzte Glied der Aufzählung in jedem Fall mit einem Schlusspunkt versehen wird.

Ich persönlich finde, dass Kommas an einem Absatzende (damit auch am Ende eines Teils einer Aufzählung) häßlich und unmotiviert aussehen und lasse sie deswegen nach obiger Regel E2 prinzipiell weg. Eine Ausnahme mag sein, wenn die Listeneinträge eben nicht gleichrangig sind, man also über die Wahl zwischen Semikolon und Komma Unterscheidungen zwischen ihnen verdeutlichen möchte - Dann kann im Prinzip aber §71 nicht mehr gelten (der Gleichrangigkeit voraussetzt)

Answer (score 2):

Eine Strichpunktliste ist eine gewöhnliche Aufzählung von gleichrangigen Wörtern, Wortgruppenn oder Teilsätzen (im Folgenden einfach kurz **Dinge** genannt), nur dass die Dinge zur besseren Übersicht untereinander geschrieben werden. Doch was folgt daraus?

Auf der einen Seite gibt es klare Regeln, die besagen, dass die Dinge durch Kommas voneinander abgegrenzt werden (vgl. [canoonet, §71](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/Aufzaehlung.html)), außer vor dem verbindenden *und* zwischen den letzten beiden Dingen (ebd., §72). Statt des Kommas kann auch das Semikolon verwendet werden, wenn man eine härtere Abgrenzung wünscht (vgl. [canoonet, §80](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf80.html)). Den zweiten Teil Ihres Beispiels würde ich demnach so schreiben:

> Wenn Sie sich eine neue Küche wünschen,
>
> - vereinbaren Sie, am besten telefonisch, einen Beratungstermin,
> - legen wir Ihnen mehrere Entwürfe vor,
> - montieren wir die neue Küche, schließen die Wasser- und Abwasserleitungen <s>an und schließen</s>**sowie** die Elektrogeräte an **und**
> - entsorgen wir Ihre alte**n** Küchenmöbel, und zwar am selben Tag.

Beachten Sie, dass der letzte Eintrag mit einem Punkt endet, weil das gesamte Gebilde einen vollständigen Satz darstellt.

Auf der anderen Seite dienen die Regeln der Kommasetzung bei Aufzählungen dazu, die einzelnen Dinge beim Lesen klar voneinander abgrenzen zu können. Bei einer Strichpunktliste ist diese Abgrenzung aber schon aufgrund der optischen Struktur möglich, sodass die Regeln zur Kommasetzung hier ihren Zweck verlieren. Ich persönlich würde bei einer Strichpunktliste, die nicht Bestandteil eines Satzes ist, die Kommas und das letzte verbindende *und* weglassen. Den ersten Teil Ihres Beispiel würde ich daher so schreiben:

> Eine Küche erhalten <s>sie</s>**Sie** bei uns in folgenden Schritten:
>
> - ein Beratungstermin, am besten telefonisch vereinbart
> - mehrere Entwürfe <s>beim</s>**bei**/nach dem Termin
> - Küchenmontage, inkl. Anschluss von Wasser- und Abwasserleitungen <s>und</s>**sowie** Anschluss von Elektrogeräten
> - Entsorgung des alten Küchenmöbels, und zwar am selben Tag

Comment: Wenn Sie sich eine neue Küche wünschen, vereinbaren Sie, am besten telefonisch, einen Beratungstermin, legen wir Ihnen mehrere Entwürfe vor (...)  diese beiden Nebensätze haben verschiedene Subjekte, daher kann man daraus nicht wirklich einen aufzählenden Satz bilden, der auch nur ansatzweise vernünftig klingt. Etwas anderes wäre es, wenn es im ersten Teil hieße "geben wir Ihnen einen Beratungstermin" - dann wäre die Ein-Staz-Variante mit Kommata in der Tat eleganter.

Comment: @Volker Doch kann man. Es ist dann eben eine Aufzählung mehrerer Sätze, die durch Kommas getrennt wurden. Dass das nicht schön ist, ist eine andere Frage. Dann müsste man es aber völlig anders schreiben, und das möchte der OP nicht.

Comment: @Volker Hier mal eine einfache Aufzählung dreier Dinge: _Heute koche ich das Essen, machst du das Bad und ruhen sich die andern aus._

Comment: @Björn: Das ist die Crux bei dieser Sache - welche Variante geht und welche nicht bzw. welche formal geht aber ungelenk klingt, hängt eben stark von der konkreten Formulierung ab. Eine davon unabhängige Lösung, wie der OP sie sich wünscht, ist somit eigentlich nicht möglich.

Answer (score 0):

Antwort nur vom Sprachgefühl her, ohne irgendwelche Regelwerke zu konsultieren:

In der unteren Variante ergibt jeweils einer der Punkte zusammen mit der Einleitung einen vollständigen Satz, daher sollte jeder mit einem Punkt enden. Ein Komma oder eine Verknüpfung mit "und" wären nur dann möglich, wenn die Sätze bzw. Satzteile so formuliert sind, dass sie auch zusammenhängend noch Sinn ergeben grammatikalisch richtig sind. Dazu wären aber konkrete Beispiele erforderlich, für den allgemeinen Fall kann man das nicht zulassen.

Im der oberen Variante würde ich auf jegliche abschließende Satzzeichen verzichten. Aber auch hier gilt, dass in konkreten Einzelfällen abweichende Lösungen besser sein können.

Comment: @user49915 _"[...] ergibt jeweils einer der Punkte **zusammen mit der Einleitung** einen vollständigen Satz"_, also z.B. _Wenn Sie sich eine neue Küche wünschen, legen wir Ihnen mehrere Entwürfe vor._

Answer (score 0):

Wortgruppen, die nicht als vollständige Sätze oder Satzteile auftreten, werden nicht durch Satzzeichen abgeschlossen. Immerhin besteht kein Bedarf dafür, wenn die Gestaltung die Wortgruppe hinreichend absetzt.

Für ganze Sätze, die ggf auch listenartig aufgezählte Wortgruppen enthalten, würde ich mich an der Interpunktion der Gesetzestexte orientieren:

> (1) Mit Freiheitsstrafe bis zu drei Jahren oder mit Geldstrafe wird bestraft, wer
>
> 1.
>   im Inland Kennzeichen einer der in § 86 Abs. 1 Nr. 1, 2 und 4 bezeichneten Parteien oder Vereinigungen verbreitet oder öffentlich, in einer Versammlung oder in von ihm verbreiteten Schriften (§ 11 Abs. 3) verwendet oder
>
> 2.
>   Gegenstände, die derartige Kennzeichen darstellen oder enthalten, zur Verbreitung oder Verwendung im Inland oder Ausland in der in Nummer 1 bezeichneten Art und Weise herstellt, vorrätig hält, einführt oder ausführt.
>
> [§ 86a, Abs. 1 StGB]

Beachte den Punkt am Ende

in § 46 wird ganz auf Aufzählungszeichen verzichtet. Allein durch den Satz mittels Zeilenumbrüchen wird ein entsprechender Effekt erzielt. Nunja, nicht nur, die Kommae helfen auch:

> (2) Bei der Zumessung wägt das Gericht die Umstände, die für und gegen den Täter sprechen, gegeneinander ab. Dabei kommen namentlich in Betracht:
>
> die Beweggründe und die Ziele des Täters, besonders auch rassistische, fremdenfeindliche oder sonstige menschenverachtende,
>
> die Gesinnung, die aus der Tat spricht, und der bei der Tat aufgewendete Wille,
>
> das Maß der Pflichtwidrigkeit,
>
> die Art der Ausführung und die verschuldeten Auswirkungen der Tat,
>
> das Vorleben des Täters, seine persönlichen und wirtschaftlichen Verhältnisse sowie
>
> sein Verhalten nach der Tat, besonders sein Bemühen, den Schaden wiedergutzumachen, sowie das Bemühen des Täters, einen Ausgleich mit dem Verletzten zu erreichen.
>
> [§ 46, Abs. 2 StGB]

Dabei wird nach dem Doppelpunkt nicht groß-geschrieben, denn es beginnt kein formvollendeter Satz. Die Aufzählung ist teil des gesamten Absatzes.